# How to declare and implement a struct that keeps track of a collection of structs?

Tags: rust

I have a struct, call it `Master`, that needs to have a field `slaves` that is a collection of `Slave`s. When added to the `Master`, each `Slave` needs to be tagged with an unique id assigned to it by the `Master`.

The way I'm trying to do this currently is like so:

```
pub struct Master {
    slaves: VecMap<Slave>
}

impl Master {
    // omitted constructor
    // fn get_unique_id(&self) -> usize {...}

    pub fn add_slave(&mut self, slave: &mut Slave) {
        let new_id = self.get_unique_id();
        slave.set_id(new_id);
        self.slaves.insert(new_id, *slave); 
        // Previous line causes "cannot move out of borrowed content" error
    }

    pub fn get_slave(&self, id: usize) -> Option<&Slave> {
        self.slaves.get(&id)
    }
}
```

How should I declare the field of slaves (`VecMap` of refs or values) and implement these methods properly?

Comment: Dietrich Epp was right on the money with his now-deleted answer, specifically the first suggestion. It was just missing a `mut` (`&mut self, mut slave: Slave`). That doesn't even influence the function signature (one could also omit it and write `let mut slave = slave;` as the first line of the body). I hope he sees this and brings the answer back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Containers *contain* the value. In this case, you are taking a *reference* (`slave: &mut Slave`) and then attempting to **steal the ownership** of the `Slave` inside your function. This is a big no-no, as the caller of this method wouldn't know that you had consumed the item.

Instead, give up the ownership of your item when adding it:

```
pub fn add_slave(&mut self, slave: Slave) {
    let mut slave = slave; // let us mutate it, now that we own it 
    let new_id = self.get_unique_id();
    slave.set_id(new_id);
    self.slaves.insert(new_id, slave); 
}
```

I prefer to accept the item (`slave: Slave`) and then make it mutable in the function body. That way, callers of the method don't need to care about implementation details. You could also declare the argument as `mut slave: Slave` if this bothers you.

Another alternative would be to change your struct to hold `&mut Slave` items instead, but my guess is that you want the first solution.